# How can I change default java version?

Tags: java, cmd, version

I have jdk17 and I need to use jdk1.8 . But when I try to ask java version from Command Prompt ( with this command -> java -version) it says jdk17 . How can I easily manipulate this, Thanks.

I tried to delete jdk17 and it changed, but I have to use both (jdk17 and jdk1.8). I need to manage java version easily

Comment: Set up your environment so all you need to do is set `JAVA_HOME` at the command line

Comment: Wrong reason to close. Specifying a default JDK falls under the category of programming tools. And this is one of the most common problems for newbie programmers. Could be closed instead as a duplicate, so no need to re-open.

Answer (score 1):

[*SDKMAN!*](https://sdkman.io/usage) is probably what you're after. This set of [shell scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) will allow you to install different Java versions and easily switch among them. In the documentation you can find everything you need to start off. You can easily switch from one JDK to another as your default.

If you're using it in a project, you will probably need to set up your IDE to use the right version.

Alternatively [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) can also do the trick, but it needs further configuration and I personally find SDKMan easier to use.